# react-intl vs react-i18next for ReactJS internationalization (i18n)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization, react-intl, react-i18next

I need to build a multilanguage application using ReactJS. The application needs a custom dictionary for different languages as well as automatic formatting of date/time, numbers and currency.

From all I´ve seen there are 2 very popular libraries:

**[react-intl](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl)** and **[react-i18next](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next)**

What would be the advantages between one and another ?
What is the most supported and popular one ?

What is the general choice for a ReactJS application supporting multiple languages ?

Comment: The main developer for react-intl left Yahoo for Apple in March and doesn't seem to be involved any longer.  The status of the project seems unclear.

Comment: 3 years later, react-intl seems to be going strong.

Comment: [react-intl-universal](https://fe-tool.com/react-intl-universal) is a React internationalization package developed by Alibaba Group. It can be used not only in React Component but also in Vanilla JS.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## [js-lingui](https://github.com/lingui/js-lingui)

I would like to present an alternative i18n libraries which I develop.

- works both with Vanilla JS (`lingui-i18n`) and React (`lingui-react`)
- `lingui-react` is the only library which fully supports inline components  and rich formatting (see below)
- build on top of ICU MessageFormat
- includes also CLI (`lingui-cli`) for building message catalogs
- it uses Flow types and a lot of validation during compile time to catch obvious errors in MessageFormat

### Syntax

ICU MessageFormat is very flexible as it supports variables, plurals, ordinals, choices, number/date formatting and is also extensible. However, complex messages are a bit difficult to write.

`lingui-i18n` provides convenient syntax using ES6 tagged template literals, while `lingui-react` provides similar syntax using React Components

#### Vanilla JS

```
import { i18n } from 'lingui-i18n'

i18n.t`Hello World`
i18n.t`Hello, my name is ${name}`
i18n.plural({ value: count, one: "# book", other: "# books" })
```

More examples in [lingui-i18n docs](https://github.com/lingui/js-lingui/tree/master/packages/lingui-i18n)

#### React

```
import React from 'react'
import { Trans, Plural } from 'lingui-react'

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const name = "Fred"
    const count = 42

    return (
      <div>
      // Static text
      <Trans>January</Trans>

      // Variables
      <Trans>Hello, my name is {name}</Trans>

      // Components
      <Trans>See the <a href="/more">description</a> below.</Trans>

      // Plurals
      <Plural 
        value={count} 
        zero={<strong>No books</strong>}
        one="# book" 
        other="# books" 
      />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

[docs](https://github.com/lingui/js-lingui) are part of `js-lingui` main docs.

### Inline components and rich formatting

I started writing this lib because I wanted a) easier syntax and b) full support for inline components.

Both `react-intl` and `react-i18next` have very limited support for rich text and inline components. You can either use basic html tags inside components (`This is <strong>bold</strong> text.`) or inject components as variables (`This is {el} text.` where `el = <strong>bold</strong>`).

The problem with the 1st approach is that you can't use custom React components. The problem with the 2nd approach is that translator works with 2 messages instead of one (`This is {el} text.` and `bold`). This is actually pretty bad because you need to translate the whole sentence to keep context.

With `lingui-react` you can use *any* React components inside translations and the message is extracted in one piece:

```
<Trans>See the <Link to="/more">description</Link> below.</Trans>
// for translator: See the <0>description</0> below.
```

Another advantage of this solution is that component name and props are hidden in extracted message. I remember how we spent a lot of time updating translations only after we changed `class` on the inner element.

Just compare it with interpolation in [react-i18next](https://react.i18next.com/components/interpolate.html) or [react-intl](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/Components#formattedmessage).

### Requirements

Both `lingui-i18n` and `lingui-react` require presets to make everything work. This is a problem if you want to use it with Create React App as you need to either eject or fork `react-scripts`.

Comment: Very interesting analysis, but this is not correct anymore, react-i18next now provide the two feature you speak about: full component interpolation and messages extraction
take a look at https://react.i18next.com/components/trans-component

Comment: If you don't want to eject. You can use craco to add webpack configuration: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco

Comment: @Jo-Go the correct link to the documentation is now: https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component

Comment: Really glad I found this! Absolutely brilliant library with all the features and none of the bloat/boilerplate!

Answer (score 9):

The general choice is react-intl, which is widely more popular than react-i18next. It currently has 4.5k vs react-i18next's 300 stars on github.
It is the go-to solution for localization in React.

Here's a tutorial to get started:
https://medium.freecodecamp.com/internationalization-in-react-7264738274a0

Comment: https://medium.com/@jamuhl/i18n-frameworks-the-unfair-showdown-8d436cd6f470

https://www.i18next.com/overview/comparison-to-others

Comment: GitHub stars are a bad indicator of popularity. https://www.npmtrends.com/react-intl-vs-react-i18next The actual usage numbers are almost identical.

Comment: @SamBokai Looking at the graph your posted, at the time of writing there was a 12x difference (73k to 6k) in favor of react-intl. Since then react-i18next did a tremendous job of catching up.

Comment: @whyp Good point!

Comment: According to npmtrends.com, the usage of  i18next is increasing while react-intl follows an almost horizontal path.

Answer (score 4):

Try https://github.com/alibaba/react-intl-universal which is developed by Alibaba Group.
yahoo/react-intl can only be applied in view layer such as React.Component. For Vanilla JS file, there’s no way to internationalize it. For example, the following snippet is general form validator used by many React.Component in our apps.

```
export default const rules = {
  noSpace(value) {
    if (value.includes(' ')) {
      return 'Space is not allowed.';
    }
  }
};
```

[alibaba/react-intl-universal](https://github.com/alibaba/react-intl-universal) is simple but powerful. It doesn’t change behavior of components.  And can used in JSX and normal JS file.

See [demo of react-intl-universal](https://fe-tool.com/react-intl-universal)