# react-i18next: interpolation of link in HTML tag in the middle of the text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I am using react, [i18next](http://i18next.com/) and [react-i18next](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next). I would like to have some translatable text with HTML link in the middle of the text which is interpolated in react, something like this:

```
This is my text with <a href="{{link}}">a beautiful link</a> in the middle of the text
```

The solution below works, but the problem is that I need to interpolate the link in react so it can't be hard-coded in label files:

```
"my-label": "This is my text with <a href=\"http://google.com\">a beautiful link</a> in the middle of the text"

[...]

<Interpolate i18nKey="my-label" useDangerouslySetInnerHTML />
```

It seems like this is much better:

```
"my-label": "This is my text with {{link}} in the middle of the text",
"link" "a beautiful link"

[...]

const { url } = props;
const link = <a href={url}>{t('link')}</a>

<Interpolate i18nKey="my-label" link={link} />
```

Could be the solution, however the app is translated into many languages and a quality of translations really matters so I prefer to have the whole text in one line for translators (this is important especially for languages which have cases).

Is there any way how to get working something like this (or is there any way how to solve it completely differently)?

```
"my-label": "This is my text with <a href=\"{{link}}\">a beautiful link</a> in the middle of the text"

[...]

const { url } = props;

<Interpolate i18nKey="my-label" useDangerouslySetInnerHTML link={url} />
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

With react-i18next v4.4.0 we introduced a new component *Trans*:

```
<Trans i18nKey="optionalKey">See the <Link to="/more">description</Link> below.</Trans>
```

The json would be: `See the <1>description</1> below.`

or even more complex:

```
<Trans i18nKey="userMessagesUnread" count={count}>
Hello <strong title={t('nameTitle')}>{{name}}</strong>, you have {{count}} unread message. <Link to="/msgs">Go to messages</Link>.
</Trans>
```

The new feature is documented here: https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component

Comment: If you are having problems with missingKey errors it's likely a namespace problem. Details are here https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/issues/867

Comment: Answer should be updated to show the t function being passed as a prop to the Trans component. ie <Trans t={t}  i18nKey="optionalKey">

Comment: Can you have conditional logic among the children of the Trans component?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I might be misunderstanding, but does this mean that the text inside Trans needs to be kept in sync with the JSON? If so, it does not seem very convenient, as it is no longer serving as an immutable key.

Comment: It seems that these texts do not need to be synchronised. I was able to use `X<a href>Y</a>Z` (with XYZ really!) as children of `Trans`, and it worked! In the JSON, I had the actual string (e.g. `This is a text with <1>a link</1> inside`)

Answer (score 7):

This is the common problem of `react-intl` and `react-i18next` - both libs have very limited support of inline components and rich-text formatting inside translations (I've already described it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44599576/1535540) with more details).

If you're still at the beginning of your project, you might want to consider different i18n library - [js-lingui](https://github.com/lingui/js-lingui) (disclaimer: I'm the author). It's the first (and so far the only) library with full support for inline components.

You simply write:

```
<Trans>See the <Link to="/more">description</Link> below.</Trans>
```

and your translators will work with message `See the <0>description</0> below.`

The only price is you need to use extra babel plugin, which makes it possible.

Answer (score 7):

Since nobody talks here how to put the text with a link in **JSON only** I will show you how

**JSON:**

`json_key: "text <0>link</0> text"`

**React:**

```
<Trans
    i18nKey="json_key"
    components={[<Link to="/" />]}
/>
```

Comment: And with version 11.6.0, you can also name your components:

```json:
"json_key": "text <firstLink>link</firstLink> text"
```
 and 
```jsx:
<Trans  i18nKey="json_key" components={{ firstLink: <Link to="/" /> }} />
```

Note that names you choose for components must NOT be an existing self-closing HTML tag names (e.g. link, img, br, ...).

See more: https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component#alternative-usage-which-lists-the-components-v11.6.0

Answer (score 1):

You only need to use t attribute to link the Trans tag to the language file. What you have between the tags is not important

```
<Trans i18nKey="cookieConsent.content" t={t}>
    x<Link to="/#privacy-policy">y</Link>z<Link to="/#legal">w</Link>
</Trans>
```

Comment: Nice! Is it some new feature? In which version has it been added?

Comment: @KnutHolm I don't know, I'm new to react-i18next. My version is 11.8.15

Comment: Every example on the net shows you how to write the react code for `Trans`, but no one will offer up what the translation file looks like. This is the most confusing API i've probably ever seen in my professional career.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet of what worked for me:

**React:**

```
import { Trans, useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

const PrivacyPolicy = () => {
  const [t] = useTranslation("privacyPolicy");
  return (
    <>
      <h1 className="heading mb-3">{t("privacy_policy.heading")}</h1>

      <p className="content">
       <Trans
          i18nKey={t("privacy_policy.content.para1")}
          values={{ link: "myapp.com" }}
          components={{ anchor: <Link to={"/"} /> }}
       />
      </p>
    </>
  );
};


export default PrivacyPolicy;
```

**Json:**

```
{
  "privacy_policy": {
    "heading": "Privacy Policy",
    "content": {
      "para1": "At MyAPP, accessible from <anchor>{{link}}</anchor>, one of our main priorities is the privacy of our visitors. This Privacy Policy document contains types of information that is collected and recorded by MyApp and how we use it.",
      "para2": "If you have additional questions or require more information about our Privacy Policy, do not hesitate to <anchor>{{link}}</anchor>.",
      "para3": "This Privacy Policy applies only to our online activities and is valid for visitors to our website with regards to the information that they shared and/or collect in MyApp. This policy does not apply to any information collected offline or via channels other than this website."
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Link not working in "react": "^18.2.0" and "react-i18next": "^14.0.1". However anchor tag HTML is fine.

json_key (JSON):

```js
{
somelink: "<anchorlink>Some text needed here</anchorlink>"
}
```

JSX (React):

```js
<Trans
i18nKey="somelink"
components={{anchorlink: <a href="/"></a>}}
/>
```

Answer (score -2):

`<Interpolate i18nKey="my-label" useDangerouslySetInnerHTML link={url} />` 
was added a few weeks ago and does allow inserting such translations containing html fragments - just be aware this is dangerous if url comes from userinput and contains malicious code (xss attack)

As i see this was added last year: https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/pull/195/files

But this will wrap per default a span around every part before/after {{link}} so that might not be what you need...but the solution is rather simple - do not use interpolate component but regular interpolation on the t function:

`<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={t('my-label', { link: yourURL }} />`

Comment: obviously this supports only wrapping those parts in a extra component (default span)