# react-i18n links inside array of strings

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I have a react application with multiple translations. There I have an array of strings which look something like this:

```
someKey: [
    "Here is some Text",
    "Here is another Text with a link: example.com",
    "Here is more Text with links: example.com, another-example.com",
]
```

I get the strings with this and loop through them and put each string in a JSX Tag:

```js
t("someKey", {returnObjects: true})
```

But I also want the links to be rendered like a link, so I tried this:

```
someKey:[
    "Here is some Text",
    "Here is another Text with a link: <a href='https://example.com'>example.com</a>",
    "Here is more Text with links: <a href='https://example.com'>example.com</a>, <a href='https://another-example.com'>another-example.com</a>",
]
```

Now, the HTML is rendered with the `<a>` tag as text and not a link (like escaped characters). How can I fix this to render it without escaping the HTML?

I have checked and tried these links:

- https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component#using-with-react-components
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/71457015/15230022
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/44802651/15230022

**Edit:**
The problem with the linked Stack Overflow answers are, that these solutions can't be mixed with the array variant. I think if I had a `string` instead of a `string[]`, it could work as expected.